# Converting java object to xml using jackson in mule project

Tags: java, xml, jackson, mule

I am working on mule project where I am trying to convertmy custom java object to xml string using jackson library. I added latest version of jackson libraries as maven dependency. But getting same error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.withDefaultPrettyPrinter(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig;
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:86)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:49)
    at org.learning.model.service.ServiceConfigurationTest.test(ServiceConfigurationTest.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I added the below dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Maven Dependency tree is given below.

```
$ mvn dependency:tree | grep jackson
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.11:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.11:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.11:provided
[INFO] |     |  \- com.github.fge:jackson-coreutils:jar:1.8:provided
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.7.4:compile
```

[Maven Dependencies Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca0Xu.png)

Comment: Sumit chances are there is a conflicting and possibly a different version of Jackson loaded. Can you print mvn dependency:tree and post it please ?

Comment: Added as per your comment. I can see org.codehaus.jackson as extra dependency .. trying to remove this dependency and will update.